# Как интегрировать виджет Инстаграм на сайт?

Tags: api, instagram

Промониторил данную тему и вижу, что плагины и виджеты все платные.
В документации инстаграма для разработчиков сходу разобраться также не получилось.
Есть ли возможность посредством API инстаграма разместить на сайте вывод изображений своего аккаунта в Инстаграме?

Comment: "Есть ли возможность посредством API инстаграма разместить на сайте вывод изображений своего аккаунта в Инстаграме?" -- Да. Каков вопрос, такой и ответ.

Comment: а как это сделать?